# How to add values future prediction on LSTM Timeseries Forecast?

Tags: python, plot, deep-learning, lstm, forecast

I have code here for LSTM Time Series for a CSV file, just want to add future data from that CSV and plot them.

note:

1. Waktu = Date
2. column one = Date (Waktu), column two = Temperature
3. it has 502 data

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

lokasi='C:/Users/HP Elitebook X360/Downloads/Nino 34 (ncep).csv'
df = pd.read_csv(lokasi)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Waktu'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

'''
plt.figure (figsize = (16, 8))
plt.title('Close Price History')
plt.plot(df['Temperature'])
plt.xlabel('Waktu', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Temperature', fontsize=18)
#plt.show()
'''

#Create a new dataframe with only the 'Close column
data= df.filter(['Temperature'])
#Convert the dataframe to a numpy array
dataset = data.values
#Get the number of rows to train the model on
training_data_len = math.ceil( len(dataset)*.8)
future_data_len = math.ceil(len(dataset)*.8)
#Scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

#Create the training data set
#Create the scaled training data set
train_data= scaled_data[0: training_data_len, :]
#Split the data into x_train and y_train data sets
x_train = []
y_train = []

interval=30
for i in range(interval, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-interval:i, 0])
    y_train.append(train_data[i,0])
if i<=interval:
    print(x_train)
    print(y_train)
    print()

#convert the x_train and y_train to numpy array
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
#x_train.shape

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))

#Build LSTM
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))

#compile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
#train model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1)
#create test data set
#create new array containing scaled values from index 341 to 400
test_data = scaled_data[training_data_len - interval:,:]
#create the data sets x_test and y_test
x_test = []
y_test =dataset[training_data_len:,:]
for i in range(interval, len(test_data)):
    x_test.append(test_data[i-interval:i, 0])

#convert the data to a numpy array
x_test = np.array(x_test)
#reshape data
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
#get model predicted price values
predictions=model.predict(x_test)
predictions=scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)
#get the RMSE
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(((predictions- y_test)**2)))
#plot the data
train = data[:training_data_len]
valid = data[training_data_len:]
valid['Predictions']=predictions

#visualize data
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Model LSTM Nino 3.4')
plt.xlabel('Waktu', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Temperature', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(train['Temperature'], linewidth=2)
plt.plot(valid[['Temperature','Predictions']], linewidth=2)
plt.legend(['Train', 'Val', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

and there is the result
[Result Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BSf4.png)

How to get future forecast for LSTM Prediction like picture below?

[Hope Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgNbm.png)